# How can I customize the .ui-dialog content?

Tags: jquery, css, primefaces

I would like to customize the .ui-dialog-content in a Dialog in JSF primefaces.
But I don´t want to override the other dialogs.
It´s only for one dialog - I don´t wanna have a padding for the dialog content (it´s a dialog for a image). This means padding: 0px;

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Primefaces, but can you not provide the single dialog it's own unique *id*, and then apply the appropriate style to the id? If this was a DOM element on an HTML page, I would give that one Dialog an id 

`<div class=".ui-dialog-content" id="uniqueID">some_content</div>`, 

and then apply some style in jquery (as that is one of your supplied tags) `$('#uniqueID').css("padding", "0px")`

Comment: hm - no this doesn´t work

Comment: Can you provide the version of primefaces you're using? Again, very slight on details so far.

Comment: I´m using Primefaces 5.3

Comment: Also, what does "no this doesn't work" mean? Did you try it and it didn't work, or are you saying that what I proposed cannot be tried in PrimeFaces?

Comment: I´ve just try it, but it does not work

Comment: Okay, on page 181 of the user guide for PrimeFaces 5.3. ([link](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf)), it says that the Dialog class has a property "*id*", which is described as a "Unique identifier of the component". This leads be to believe that you *can* assign the component a unique ID and then perform actions based off of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94457/discussion-between-internet-and-mandm).